# How to use different layoutRes with Butterknife for BaseActivityClass and ActivityExtending it?

Tags: android, butterknife

I want to use Butterknife but also having keep Drawer logic being created and maintined in a BaseActivityClass extended by all of my other Activities having different layoutIds.

Tried providing LayoutId via abstract method and inflating it manually, but Butterknife failes with error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Required view 'View' with ID 2131493000 for field 'mView' was not found. If this view is optional add '@Nullable' annotation.
```

Base Class

```
 @Bind(R.id.leftDrawer)
protected ListView mLeftDrawer;

@Bind(R.id.drawerLayout)
protected DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;

@Bind(R.id.contentFrame)
protected FrameLayout mContentFrame;

private ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;

protected abstract @LayoutRes int getContentLayout();

private Intents mIntents;

private String[] mOptionsTitles = new String[]{
        "Menu item 1",
        "Menu item 2",
        "Menu item 3"
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.drawer_activity);
    getLayoutInflater().inflate(getContentLayout(), mContentFrame);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
}
```

Activity Class

```
@Override
protected int getContentLayout() {
    return R.layout.activity_main;
}
```

At the moment I am left with an options drop Butterknife, or duplicate logic for the Drawer handling in all Activities.
Both options would prefer to avoid.

Comment: Without butterknife it works?

Comment: Yep, if I drop Binding via Butterknife in extending classes, and inflate the mContentView with:
 getLayoutInflater().inflate(getContentLayout(), mContentFrame)

in BaseClass, have no problems.
The moment I will try to use Butterknife instead findById in extending classes, Butterknife throws.

Comment: I had an issue with butterknife using "include" in my layouts. This helped me: https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/issues/396.